# git checkout をやり直したい

Tags: git

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

とした後に、もとのコミットに戻るには、どうしたら良いですか？

```
git log
```

をしても、もとのコミットを確認できません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --all` で元のコミットも含めたすべてのコミットが表示されます。

あるいは、直前のコミットに戻るだけであれば `git checkout -` で戻れます。

Comment: `git branch` とすると、
* (detached from e035d63)
branch-A
master

と出ます。このとき、branch-AにHEADを持っていくには、どうしたら良いですか？

Comment: git checkout branch-A でいいのではないでしょうか